# Execution Tree in Oracle 10 g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

I am trying to get into the statement level optimization of PL/SQL in Oracle 11 g. I would like to know what is the kind of tree(BST ?) that the optimizer builds for a query and what is the kind of traversal(pre /post/in order?) done on it ?

Answer (score 0):

In sqlplus

```
Set autotrace on explain
```

Show you execution plan tree.